# mysql query using max does not output any records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, aggregate-functions

I'm using MySQL and have the following table definition:

```
create table student_t (student id int primary key, grade int);
```

I've then populated the table with the following:

```
insert into student_t values (1, 70), (2, 90), (3, 80);
```

I want to get the id and grade for the student with the highest grade.
I try the following but no records are output.

```
select * from student_t where grade = max(grade);
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: select id, max(grade) from student_t limit 1;  Ill take a quick look at specifics at mysql for confirmation.  I wouldve just tested it myself if there was an SQLFIDDLE. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `MAX()` function directly like that in `WHERE` condition (except in `HAVING` clause). Your query should look like below using sub query

```
select * from student_t where grade in (select max(grade) from student_t);
```

Or using `ORDER BY` clause along with `LIMIT` operator like

```
select * from student_t 
order by grade desc limit 1;
```

Comment: The `order by grade desc limit 1` solution works if you are only interested in what the highest grade was or if you are certain there can only be one student with each grade. It is usually possible for more than one student to share the top grade.  If you want to know which student(s) got the top grade you need the `where grade = (select max(grade) from student_t)` variant (works with = as well as in)

Comment: @Adam, that's right but there is no harm in knowing the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

`where` clauses are applied on a row-by-row basis, as the rows are being considered for inclusion in the result set. At the time your individual rows are being considered, the results of `max()` aren't available yet. You have to use a "having" clause, which is less efficient, or use a sub-query to get the max() value separately:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student_t
HAVING grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM student_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
select field1, field2, field3, max(grade) from student
group by field1, field2, field3
having grade=max(grade)
```

or

```
SELECT * from student
having grade=max(grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is located here.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa8c0/6

```
select * from student_t order by grade desc limit 1;
```